# Prevent liclipse from replacing references to a renamed file

Tags: eclipse, pydev, file-rename, automated-refactoring, liclipse

I've swapped from Eclipse to LiClipse.

An annoyance is: when I rename a file it goes through all my code and changes the reference to the renamed file to the new name.

I DO NOT want this behavior, since I usually rename the file to make a backup before making major changes.

Can this behavior be turned off?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version at least you can select whether references should be renamed or not in the dialog which asks for the rename (or whether you want to do a simple resource rename or just change the extension).